# bitcode bundle could not be generated because Flipper-DoubleConversion was built without full bitcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, build, bitcode

I wanted to build IOS after environmental separation. However, an error occurs when building.

- this is my error

[image]

- this is my podfile

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

```
NOTE : I want use bitcode. so I not recommend change bitcode value
```

Comment: Hi @hong developer : I had same issue with you, so please let me know once you have solution to fix this. Thank you so much

Comment: @KhoaNguyễn this is my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed Filpper version

- package.json

```json
{
"react-native-flipper": "^0.135.0",
}
```

- podFile

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.135.0' }, configurations: ['DevDebug','ProdDebug','DevRelease', 'ProdRelease'])
```

Comment: @KhoaNguyễn this is my solution